# developing a plugin - trying to use wordpress database

Tags: php, plugins, fatal-error, wordpress

I'm trying to use $wpdb, and I'm having some issues. at the top of my code, i put 
global $wpdb;

and below it, I put
$wpdb->show_errors();

when I try to use this plugin, I get this error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function show_errors() on a non-object in /home/jordan/public_html/aa/wp-content/themes/jordantheme/customplugin.php on line 4

Answer (score 0):

`$wpdb` is not initialized on plugin load.

Instead, you should wrap your code in a function and hook it to wordpress:

```
function myPlugin_init(){
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->show_errors();
}
add_action('init', 'myPlugin_init');
```

Comment: after i do this, i get the following error:    Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_action() in /home/jordan/public_html/aa/wp-content/themes/jordantheme/customplugin.php on line 4

Comment: Hmm...sounds like wordpress hasn't loaded *at all*. This is definitely **not good**. How are you accessing that page you're on?